# PHP / CodeIgniter: How to solve mongo.so problem

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, php-mongodb

I have written a new PHP application with the CodeIgniter Framework. Oftenly the following error is thrown:

```
Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It is a completely fresh installation and I do not use this mongo.so library anywhere. Also on the configuration of Apache or PHP I did not change anything special.

Probably the problem can be solved by installing php-mongodb on the system. But maybe someone has a better idea to solve the problem.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows, Linux or MacOS?

Comment: I use a Ubuntu 16.04 Linux

Comment: Did you not enable mongo in your php.ini? extension=mongodb.so

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem solved myself.

In `/etc/php/7.0/mods_available` was a file `user.ini`, which included the mongo extension. Don't know why, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using MongoDB, you can safely do this

```
nano /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mongodb.ini
```

Then, comment the line as follow

```
#extension=mongodb.so
```

Save with ctrl+o then exit with ctrl+x

That's it!